# Boltzmann entropy of Gaussian distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

Recently I have been looking into different definitions of entropy and came across Boltzmann (unconditional) entropy:

$S=-\int_{R} dx \;p(x) \ln p(x)$

I have tried to calculate entropy of regular [Gauss distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). My logic is that if this definition makes sense, then for nice distributions it should produce reasonable results. However, it appeared to be that even in this case this entropy can be negative, see the plot below. The equation I got is:

$S(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2} (\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)+1).$

Forgive me my ignorance in stat. mech. and thermodynamics, but I cannot get it. If this entropy doesn't work even for this case, then how and under which conditions does this definition make sense? Literature and references are very welcome! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: This is correct. What is always nonnegative is the relative entropy (aka Kullback–Leibler divergence) of a probability distribution with respect to another one. You can google these terms (or probably read the wikipedia article, although I haven't checked if it is good).

Comment: What is the physical meaning though? How do I interpret it?

Comment: There is even a simplier example, a uniform distribution of width $b-a < 1$, then the height is $\frac{1}{b-a} > 1$, so the entropy will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

For a discrete distribution
$$
S= -\sum_i p_i\ln p_i
$$
is always positive as $0\le p_i\le 1$. The formula you give for $S$ has problems though. As
$$
1 = \int dx \,p(x)
$$
whatever units $x$ has (meters say, if $x$ is  length) the $p(x)$ has in the inverse units. As a consequnce $\ln p(x)$ makes no sense as you cannot take the log of a dimensionful quantity. A valid  formula must be
$$
S= -\int dx p(x)\ln ( a p(x))
$$ for some $a$ with the same dimensions  as $x$. One would like $S$ to be zero if $p(x)=\delta(x-a)$ (no uncertainty)  but that is not possible, so there is no preferred choice of $a$. As a consequence, as @Yvan Velenik says, only differences in the entropy of continuous dstributions  make sense

Comment: Yes, I am aware that differential definitions of information do not have this problem. However, this definition is still being used. I wonder if there is someone aware of limitations and physical meaning of this quantity. See ref: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704004480